# login display for the fos user

Tags: symfony

I had some problems using php bin/console fos:user: create in my project so I had copied the vendor of another project that is working well  and then I created a file User.php but at the display of the login . I receive this [image: display for my project] while in the other project it replaces the other attributes security.login.username by username and security.login.password by password ,etc [image: display of the project i copied the vendor from]

```html
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
    {% if csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
    {% endif %}

    <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" autocomplete="username" />

    <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" autocomplete="current-password" />

    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
    <label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}</label>

    <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your translator to ~ in your app/config/config.yml file.

```
# app/config/config.yml

framework:
    translator: ~
```

Comment: I don't have a file called config.yml under config directory , do I have to create it ?

Comment: Which version of symfony are you using?